# UAC for accessing private key

Tags: windows-7, uac, privacy, private-key

I like that Windows (Vista and later versions) asks me for a confirmation (UAC) before executing any new application.
Can I somehow configure UAC to ask for my confirmation EVERYTIME an application is trying to read my SSH private key file?
I do NOT want to put a (long) passphrase for reasons beyond the scope of this question.